# Passing multiple pieces of data via command line to be separately evaluated using ARGV

Tags: ruby

I have a fairly straightforward script where I need to be able to take in data passed in either from the command line or a file and then depending on the first command (ARGV[0] in the case of data coming from the command line) either instantiate a new instance of the only class in my script or alter an attribute of an existing instance of the class, and then output a summary of what happened after I'm done iterating over the input data.

I think I know what I'm doing when it's a file, but I'm a bit stuck on how to do this when data is passed via the command line.

I know with just one piece of data I'd just do:

```
ruby filename.rb command1 command2 command3
```

And within my script I'd have something like

```
instance = ClassName.new(ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
```

..but in this situation, I want to be able to do it for several sets of those 3 commands. So something like:

```
ruby filename.rb command1 command2 command3
ruby filename.rb anothercommand1 anothercommand2 anothercommand3
```

..and repeat until all the data is in, and then call the summary method. Any advice on how to implement this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I properly understood what you want to do:

```
ARGV.each_slice(3) { |a1, a2, a3|
  # NB: a2 and/or a3 may be nil here if ARGV.size % 3 ≠ 0
  puts "#{a1}×#{a2}×#{a3}"
}
puts "Init NOW"
```

Yielding:

```
~ ruby a.rb arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7
# arg1×arg2×arg3
# arg4×arg5×arg6
# arg7××
# Init NOW
```

**UPD**
After a clarification of the task:

```
class Operator
  attr_accessor :a1, :a2, :a3, :a4 
  def initialize attrs
    @a1, @a2, @a3, @a4 = attrs
  end 
  def begin
    puts "[BEGIN] ⇒ 1: #{@a1}, 2: #{@a2}, 3: #{@a3}"
  end 
  def add 
    puts "[ADD]   ⇒ 1: #{@a1}, 2: #{@a2}, 3: #{@a3}, 4: #{@a4}"
  end 
  def subtract
    puts "[SUBTR] ⇒ 1: #{@a1}, 2: #{@a2}, 3: #{@a3}, 4: #{@a4}"
  end 
end

meth, *args = ARGV

Operator.new(args).send (meth.to_sym)
```

Which gives:

```
~ ruby a.rb add arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
# [ADD]   ⇒ 1: arg1, 2: arg2, 3: arg3, 4: arg4
~ ruby a.rb begin arg1 arg2 arg3
# [BEGIN] ⇒ 1: arg1, 2: arg2, 3: arg3
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity -- that would work for what my poorly worded question asked for, but I'm actually dealing with a situation where my first argument will be one of 3-4 (begin/add/subtract) different things. If my first argument is begin, I'll have 3 total arguments in that statement, but if it's one of the other 2 I'll have 4 arguments in the statement. So I'm looking for a way to basically have separate ARGV's for each 'line' of data, or some other equivalent way of doing this. Hopefully that's clearer than my initial post.

Comment: Please see the update to the answer. If you need some comments to the code, don’t hesitate to ask.